# Rspec2: response.should render_template("new") after invalid params fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am testing a controller in RSpec2 and for both my create and update actions, when passed invalid params, the controller should render either the "new" or "edit" templates respectively.  It is doing that, but my test never passes.

```
describe "with invalid params" do
    before(:each) do
      User.stub(:new) { mock_user(:valid? => false, :save => false) }
    end

    it "re-renders the 'new' template" do
      post :create, :company_id => mock_company.id
      response.should render_template("new")
    end
  end
```

Results in this:

```
re-renders the 'new' template
expecting <"new"> but rendering with <"">
```

Here is the controller action:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html {
      flash[:notice] = "#{@user.full_name} was added to #{@company.name}."
      redirect_to company_users_url(@company)
    }
  else
    logger.debug @user.errors
    format.html{
      render :new
    }
  end
end
```

This problem also seems to be isolated to this controller.  I have almost identical code running another controller and it is fine.  I am not sure where the problem could be.

**Update:**
Here are the two mock methods

```
def mock_user(stubs={})
  @mock_user ||= mock_model(User, stubs).as_null_object
end

def mock_company(stubs={})
  (@mock_company ||= mock_model(Company).as_null_object).tap do |company|
    company.stub(stubs) unless stubs.empty?
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `mock_user` and `mock_company`?

Comment: We're still missing something. How do you set the values of `@company` and `@user` in the controller (maybe using a before filter?). Does the controller actually call `User.new`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out it was a problem with stubbing and CanCan.  CanCan was loading the resources and uses some different methods than what I thought.

Comment: Well that was back in March, so I would have to go dig it up to find the answer.  Also I am sure CanCan has changed a lot since then, so even then the answer probably wouldn't be relevant

Comment: Getting the exact same error, but not using CanCan. At least I know I'm not alone

Comment: I'm still getting this error and I'm using the latest version of both CanCan and Rspec. I just removed CanCan filters from my controller and the problem is still there ¬¬